# How do I write text in a square that i Draw , in Consol Application?

Tags: c#

Bassicaly i need to divide the square in 4 part and print different text in every part. And I have wrecked my brain so far. Any advise is really apreciated.

```
static void drawquare(int l, int h, int x, int y)
        {
            string tvkant = "\x250C"; //Top left point 
            string thkant = "\x2510"; //Top right point
            string bvkant = "\x2514"; //bottom left point 
            string bhkant = "\x2518"; //bottom right
            string vside = "\x2502"; //left side
            string hside = "\x2502"; //right side
            string top = "\x2500"; //Top 
            string bund = "\x2500"; //Bottom
            for (int i = 1; i < l; i++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x + i, y);
                Console.Write(top);
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x + i, y + h);
                Console.Write(bund);
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < h; i++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y + i);
                Console.Write(vside);
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x + l, y + i);
                Console.Write(hside);
            }
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
            Console.Write(tvkant);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x + l, y);
            Console.Write(thkant);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y + h);
            Console.Write(bvkant);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x + l, y + h);
            Console.Write(bhkant);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

enter code here
```

I run this in main method.

drawquare(20, 24, 16, 20);

Comment: Instead of trying to estimate escape sequences and positioning, use a library like [Gui.cs](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/gui.cs)

Comment: First of all, you have a type in the name of the method: `drawquare`. Besides, it's not clear what problem you try to solve. Please provide more information on the requirements, what arguments does the method accept and what should be done.

Comment: Did you try anything to get those texts in the correct position, and if so, how did that work out?

Comment: Its a school assignment, and I'm not allowed to use gui.

its a booking system, so a "customer" enters their phone number and depending on what the number is starting with, the program should assign a part of the square as the room they booked. so I should have 4 rooms, and when they book, a text apears in the square- to visualize the room they booked. I already did one part with switch cases and do while loop. but I have no idea how to tackle this part

Comment: I even tried this method            // Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0," + l + h / 2 + "}", "TEXT"));

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.